# Powershell set-adcomputer issue set location

Tags: powershell

I have made this script to set/change the location attribute of computers in a specific OU.

My variable is ok but when I execute, it is not taking it line by line. 
How can I solve this.

```html
Import-module ActiveDirectory

$computers= Get-ADcomputer -Filter * -searchbase "OU=XX,OU=XXX,OU=WXXX,DC=TGE,DC=XX,DC=XX" | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}


Set-ADcomputer -identity "$computers" -Location "buildingA"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$Computers` is an [Array] Object which means it has a set of objects inside

The `Set-ADComputer` command cannot process all the array at once, to process each one of them you need to use the 'Foreach' method for example:

```
Foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
Set-ADcomputer -identity $computer -Location "buildingA"
}
```

Another Approach is add the foreach after the pipe, like this:

```
Get-ADcomputer -Filter * -searchbase "OU=XX,OU=XXX,OU=WXXX,DC=TGE,DC=XX,DC=XX" | ForEach-Object {Set-ADComputer -identity $_ -Location "buildingA"}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I now understand the Foreach method. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Try piping the output of `Get-ADcomputer` into `Set-ADcomputer`:

```
Get-ADcomputer -Filter * -searchbase "OU=XX,OU=XXX,OU=WXXX,DC=TGE" | Set-ADcomputer -Location "buildingA"
```